# Angularjs $compiling modal window contents creates orphaned controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I have a modal window that's being triggered by fancybox. When the modal shows, fancybox broadcast a "modalShown" event that an AppController listens for. In that listener, AppController calls $compile on the contents of the modal window in order to create the ModalController, interpolate, and bind events on the view.

My issue is that when I close the modal, the modal element is removed from the DOM but its bound ModalController instance is persisting somewhere. So every time I open a new window, I create a new controller, and all of these orphaned controllers are responding to events inside of the modal window.

My question is, since $compile creates the new controller, but doesn't return a reference to it, **how can I cleanup these unused controllers propagating in my app**?

Relevant code (coffee)...

Fancybox Directive

```
# sets up the fancybox on each element that triggers the modal...
# <a href="#" fancybox="templateToLoad.html">Trigger Modal</a>
@app.directive 'fancybox', ["$templateCache", "$compile", ($templateCache, $compile) ->
  (scope, element, attrs) ->
    options =
      afterShow : ->
          scope.$root.$broadcast 'modalShown', scope
    element.fancybox options
```

modal.html

```
<div class="fancybox-skin">
  <div class="fancybox-outer">
    <div class="fancybox-inner ng-scope">
      <div ng-controller="ModalController" style="..." class="ng-scope">
        <a href="#" ng-click="someAction()">Some Action in ModalController</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ModalController

```
app.controller 'ModalController', [
  '$scope', '$rootScope',($scope, $rootScope) ->

    # keeping track of controllers for debugging
    window.globalCounter ||= 0
    $scope.localCounter = window.globalCounter++

    someAction = () ->
        console.log 'action'
```

AppController

```
@app.controller "AppController", [
  "$scope", "$rootScope", "$compile", ($scope, $rootScope, $compile) ->
       $scope.$on 'modalShown', (e, localScope) ->
            console.log('compiling modal contents')
            $compile($('.fancybox-inner'))(localScope)
            $rootScope.$apply()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ModalController` you have is effectively just a function that runs to set up any functionality on its relevant `$scope` and then is never seen or heard from again. Any functionality you are still seeing left over is either left on this scope or is leaked from the controller and should be cleaned up in a `$scope.$on('$destroy', function() { ... })` block.

If the functionality is in `$watch`es or `$on`s on the scope, then they should be automatically cleaned up by angular when the scope is destroyed. If they remain, then the scope has not been destroyed when the modal is closed.

You are passing in the parent scope yourself with `$compile($('.fancybox-inner'))(localScope)`. If instead of `localScope` you use `localScope.$new()` then you would be able to safely call `.$destroy()` on this new scope when you see the modal close.

As an aside, can I suggest moving the `AppController` functionality into your `fancybox` directive and avoiding these broadcasts entirely - DOM manipulation and compilations fit much more nicely in a directive than a controller and you can more easily keep track of any new scopes you need to create.